# PDF reader plugin for android

Tags: android, html, ios, angularjs, web

I'm trying to make a online PDF library app. I need a PDF reader plugin. If anyone know any reader, then please help me.

Comment: Had you ever done a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+javascript)?

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend in this situation.

There is a handy library for reading and displaying PDFs in a view

> AndroidPdfViewer 1.x is available on AndroidPdfViewerV1 repo, where
>   can be developed independently. Version 1.x uses different engine for
>   drawing document on canvas, so if you don't like 2.x version, try 1.x.
>
> Library for displaying PDF documents on Android, with animations,
>   gestures, zoom and double tap support. It is based on PdfiumAndroid
>   for decoding PDF files. Works on API 11 (Android 3.0) and higher.
>   Licensed under Apache License 2.0.

it is located here https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

If you however want a solution that will be ideal across android, windows and iOS devices http://www.radaeepdf.com/ might be more up your street

> RadaeePDF SDK helps you to build better mobile applications. Using our
>   featured PDF reader engine's API and its set of professional features
>   is now a quick and simple procedure.
>
> RadaeePDF SDK extends your App's features with stunning PDF
>   capabilities on smartphones, tablets, notebooks, convertibles,
>   desktops.
>
> Main RadaeePDF SDK' features: PDF rendering engine for Android iOS
>   Windows 10 operating systems, PDF annotation, PDF creation, PDF
>   multimedia support.
>
> RadaeePDF SDK supports also Xamarin and Cordova development targeting
>   Android and iOS.